# .dat file how to create one based on excel document

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, cluster-analysis

I have a .csv file in my matlab folder with 38 columns and about 48 thousand entries. I was hoping on using the findcluster gui but it only accepts .dat files.

How do I create a .dat file in matlab or specifically how do I convert the .csv file into a .dat file that can be used by the matlab fcm clustering tool?

example of csv:
[image]

how would I go about creating a data file for this kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp310.html) I could find about the file format was

> The data set must have the extension .dat. For example, to load the data set, 
>   clusterdemo.dat, type findcluster('clusterdemo.dat').

I checked clusterdemo.dat and found that the data is stored in ASCII format. Therefore, try

```
a = csvread('data.csv');
save 'data.dat' a -ASCII
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename xxx.csv to xxx.dat. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should try changing extension.For changing extension you can go to folder settingand in view where we show hidden file…uncheck the hide extension for known files and now you can change the extension of any file by renaming it.

Because 
There really isn't such a thing as 'dat' format, a 'dat' file is just a text file, it could theoretically have any extension you want.It could also be delimited however you want/need, it all really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

ie what are you going to use this file for?
If it's for use with another application then the requirements of that application will probably dictate how it's delimited/structured etc.

OR simply you can save the file from the excel as .csv and then later can change the extension.

It worked for me.